# PDO prepared statement returns empty array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, statements

This returns an empty array:

```
$query_string = "select * from :table where id=1";
$args = array(":table" => "pages");
$result = $db->Query($query_string, $args);
```

This pulls and returns data from database:

```
$query_string = "select * from pages where id=1";
$result = $db->Query($query_string);
```

---

Query method:

```
public function Query($query, $arguments = null) {
    $pdo_query = $this->Connection->prepare($query);
    $pdo_query->execute($arguments);
    if($pdo_query) {
        return $pdo_query->fetchAll();
    }
}
```

I went through samples and documentation - my syntax seems to be fine. Why does the first sample of code return empty array?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you ever seen a query where table name was quoted using single quotes? Nearly every PDOStatement example tells you that you **can't bind table names as parameters**. The reason is that you'll send that parameter as either a string or integer. Since you can't single-quote table names, and their names aren't integers either, you'll end up with god knows what (most likely an error). TL;DR - you're using it wrong.

Comment: You can't bind a parameter to the table name with PDO.

Comment: Just a side note, you shouldn't SELECT * just select the columns you need.

Comment: @Ant - without context, please don't suggest such things since you can be both correct and wrong, sometimes both at the same time. Right approach depending on situation is what's universal truth. Also, if `SELECT *` wasn't useful, it wouldn't be implemented.

Comment: @N.B. SELECT * is NEVER a good idea and considered LAZY.

Comment: In my case 'SELECT *' is rather necessary as I am pulling all data about a specific post from a specific row(WHERE id=:id).

Comment: @Ant - you're obviously new to this business. I won't argue with you since you clearly have 0 clue what you're talking about. One day, when you see enterprise systems with 255 columns, you'll stop spouting nonsense. Yes, they do exist and yes, they cost a lot, are used and need maintaining.

Comment: @N.B. Thanks buddy keep up the good work. Stay focused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot bind a table name to a PDO parameter. Parameters only work for operands of comparison or assignments.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Both answers are very helpful.

Comment: It made me mad with Laravel! To overcome this we may use `sprintf` before binding.

Answer (score 2):

As said above you cannot bind the table name to a parameter, you should change your code like so

```
$query_string = "select * from pages where id=:id";
$args = array(":id" => "1"); //the : is not necessary but as it is a non-documented feature I would always set it
$result = $db->Query($query_string, $args);
```